# .NET CF 3.5 TextBox - disabling dictionary

Tags: c#, .net, user-controls, windows-mobile, compact-framework

How to disable TextBox dictionary? While inputting characters to TextBox it displays all previously entered strings which I can't accept in my application.

Regards
Dominik Tomczak

Answer (score 1):

You need to use pinvoke to remove the auto-complete and auto-suggest functionality:

[See this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4548077/windows-mobile-6-disable-autocomplete-on-winforms-textboxes/4553163#4553163)

Answer (score 0):

TextBoxes are made to display anything a user types in them. If you want to automatically clear a TextBox on certain conditions, you'll have to handle the `TextChanged` event, or create a subclass of TextBox and override the `OnTextChanged()` method.