# Windows Mobile 6 - Disable AutoComplete on WinForms TextBoxes

Tags: windows-mobile, autocomplete

I am making a windows mobile 6 app, where I need to disable autocomplete on the textboxes that I have on my form.  Information is being scanned into them, therefore I need to disable the autocomplete/autosuggest feature.  Can I do this programmatically or do I need to manipulate registry keys?  (This is not a commercial application.)

Comment: You should really mark sharky101 as having answered your question. It worked for me.

Answer (score 22):

Use this class, it will pinvoke the SHSetInputContext method and disable\enable the hover over events for the controls.  Simply pass the controls Handle.

```
public static class InputContext
{
    private enum SHIC_FEATURE : uint
    {
        RESTOREDEFAULT = 0,
        AUTOCORRECT = 1,
        AUTOSUGGEST = 2,
        HAVETRAILER = 3,
        CLASS = 4
    }

    [DllImport("aygshell.dll")]
    private static extern int SHSetInputContext(IntPtr hwnd, SHIC_FEATURE dwFeature, ref bool lpValue);

    public static void SetAutoSuggestion(IntPtr handle, bool enable)
    {
        SHSetInputContext(handle, SHIC_FEATURE.AUTOSUGGEST, ref enable);
        SHSetInputContext(handle, SHIC_FEATURE.AUTOCORRECT, ref enable);
    }
}
```

Example:

```
InputContext.SetAutoSuggestion(txtBoxOne.Handle, false);
```

Comment: For this to compile you need to add "using System.Runtime.InteropServices;"  Otherwise perfect, helped me loads!

Comment: Best solution found so far...Wish I could double mark you post as answer :)

Comment: Just wanted to confirm that this worked for me as well. Thanks Ryan. Also, Harvey get off your butt and give Ryan the credits he deserves by marking this as the right answer ;)

Comment: I would really know how you got this solution, I would never imagine I could do something like this. thanks!