# WPF/C# (Desktop) - Disable default dictionary for TextBox, and use only custom dictionary?

Tags: c#, wpf

I am using custom Dictionary for spell check in a WPF (Desktop) TextBox, and I want to disable the default dictionary it uses. I expect the text-box to highlight all words for typos other than the ones in my custom dictionary.

According to the [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.spellcheck.customdictionaries(v=vs.110).aspx)

> All custom dictionaries for that TextBox are used **in addition to the
>   default spelling checker**.

How do I disable the default spelling checker so it only checks against my custom dictionary?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Windows Mobile 6 - Disable AutoComplete on WinForms TextBoxes](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4548077/windows-mobile-6-disable-autocomplete-on-winforms-textboxes)

Comment: Did you do anything specific to attempt to disable the built-in dictionary? Or did you think that simply using a custom dictionary would cause the control to ignore the built-in dictionary? If the latter, I find that expectation entirely unreasonable, as it's contrary to how 99.94% of the people using spellcheck would want it to work. If the former, please provide [a good, _minimal_, _complete_ code example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that reliably reproduces your problem.

Comment: FYI: from [the documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.spellcheck.customdictionaries(v=vs.110).aspx): _"All custom dictionaries for that TextBox are used in addition to the default spelling checker."_

Comment: @PeterDuniho, How do I disable the default spelling checker?

Comment: @PeterDuniho I just want to use ONLY my custom dictionary words. No words from default dictionary.

Comment: @TheLethalCoder, This is desktop development.

Comment: I see nothing in the documentation that would suggest you can do this, never mind that you should expect to be able to.

Comment: That said, it hints at a work-around: _"Spelling checker is supported only when WPF provides a default dictionary. In .NET Framework 4, WPF provides dictionaries for English, French, German, and Spanish."_ The word "supported" is vague here; maybe it means that if the thread culture is not one of those 4 languages, spellcheck won't work at all. Or maybe it just means there are only default dictionaries for those four languages, and that if you change the current thread culture, spellcheck will revert to using only a custom dictionary.

Comment: I'm interested in an answer to this question too, and disagree that it is a duplicate of the linked question to disable AutoComplete. I've made some minor edits to it in an attempt to try and get an answer for this, but I suspect Peter is correct that it is not something supported with the current implementation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think this is supported at this time, but I'd love for someone to prove me wrong.

According to [this MSDN blog article](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/text/archive/2009/10/02/custom-dictionaries.aspx)

> Custom dictionaries should be used when an application wants a set of words, which are not found in the default dictionary for a language, to not be marked as misspelled.

and

> Spelling support in WPF is limited to four languages: English,
>   Spanish, French, and German. **Custom dictionaries are designed to
>   augment the default dictionaries for these languages and not to extend
>   spelling support to other languages.** Creating a custom dictionary
>   which contains common Russian words, marking the dictionary as a
>   Russian dictionary, and adding it to the SpellCheck object of a
>   TextBox or RichTextbox will not add Russian spelling support. **If the
>   first line of a custom dictionary denotes that the dictionary is used
>   for a language which is not supported, that dictionary will be
>   ignored.**